# Taking JSON string from Django template and loading into D3 graph

Tags: javascript, json, django, d3.js

So far I am using :

```
var voltString = {{volts}};
var battVoltage = JSON.parse(voltString);
```

This is then used with :

```
.datum(battVoltage)
```

But it doesn't seem to work the same way as the example pulled from the site. Code for this is shown below, but with test data from a function.

```
  /*Wrapping in nv.addGraph allows for '0 time out render'*/
/*stores rendered charts in nv.graphs*/
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
        .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
        .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
        .y(function(d) { return d[1]/100 })
        .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
        .average(function(d) { return d.mean/100; })
        .duration(300)
        .clipVoronoi(false);
    chart.dispatch.on('renderEnd', function() {
        console.log('render complete: cumulative line with guide line');
    });

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d3.time.format('%m/%d/%y')(new Date(d))
    });

    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1%'));

    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
        /*Replace with reference to imported JSON data*/
        .datum(cumulativeTestData())
        .call(chart);

    //Could automate this?
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });
    chart.state.dispatch.on('change', function(state){
        nv.log('state', JSON.stringify(state));
    });

    return chart;
});

function cumulativeTestData() {
    return [
Some array
];
}
```

The volts String being passed in is as follows :

```
'volts': '[{"fields": {"logtime": "2013-12-13T18:12:57Z", "gen_voltage": ' '"11.63"}, "pk": 1, "model": "uploads.data"}, {"fields": ' '{"logtime": "2013-12-13T18:43:27Z", "gen_voltage": "11.47"}, ' '"pk": 2, "model": "uploads.data"}, {"fields": {"logtime": ' '"2013-12-13T19:14:00Z", "gen_voltage": "11.67"}, "pk": 3, ' '"model": "uploads.data"}, {"fields": {"logtime": ' '"2013-12-13T19:44:34Z", "gen_voltage": "11.7"}, "pk": 4, "model": ' '"uploads.data"},.....]'}
```

Comment: If you view the page source and look at what `var voltString` actually equals, is it a string?

Comment: Added in the volts String to the code in the question. I'm not sure it's an error with that, but an error with something in the javascript graph code?

Comment: If you open up your javascript console in the browser, is there any errors? If not, if you just type `> battVoltage` and see what it outputs?

Comment: I get an invalid property ID at the  var voltStr = {{volts}}; line. But I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.